# Linux softirq and SMP

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, smp, softirq

I have read that multiple instances of a softirq can be run on different cores in a multi-core system. Based on above statement, I have deduced below understanding with a example.

The system received similar hardware interrupts on its local PIC of CPU's and the same softirq gets triggered from multiple cores.
If we consider a SMP system having multiple NIC cards and at the same instance the NIC cards received packets and triggered a interrupt to a IOAPIC, The IO APIC routes the interrupt of multiple NIC cards to different cores which will trigger same softirq from different cores.
Is my understanding correct on the above scenario ?, If I am missing something, kindly share your perspective.

Thanks,

Comment: A softirq will run on the same CPU that calls `raise_softirq` in order to preserve cache.

Comment: @stark, Is it possible to have same interrupt triggered on different cores, which in turn fires a same softirq from different cores ?

Comment: `cat /proc/interrupts`

Comment: @stark, I meant, the same interrupt on different cores and same time instance without any delay, is that possible ?